# Not understanding where the ratio comes from

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

I'm completely stumped at how they come up with the ratio AB : AC. Why not AC : AB?

Where does this ratio come from? How can I get to this ratio myself? Please help.

Comment: What's the difference? Why not $\;y:x\;$ instead of $\;x:y\;$ ? What's the problem?

Comment: The difference is that 1 over square root of 3 divided by two is different than square root of 3 divided by 2 over 1. You'd get different answers

Comment: AB is found using cos 30=AC/AB and then ration AB:AC is written

Comment: @Vikram I'm not sure how you'd go from AC/AB to AB : AC. Why flip the two?

Comment: I don't get what you say, @GarthMarenghi: they're giving $$AB:AC=1:\frac{\sqrt3}2=\frac1{\frac{\sqrt3}2}=\frac2{\sqrt3}$$ Again, what's the problem?

Comment: Yes, I know. But HOW do they come up with the ratio AB : AC? They ask you for the length of the hypotenuse, and then there's this ratio AB : AC. How?

Comment: It's a basic theorem in Euclidean geometry, @GarthMarenghi : in a straight angle triangle with angles $\;30-60-90\;$ , the length of the leg opposite to the $\;30^\circ\;$ angle is half the hypotenuse's, and then apply Pythagoras Theorem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't delete my answer, apparently, because it has been accepted. But I can edit it:

I misread the small print as:

> The ratio of $AB:AC$ is $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$.

But it was in fact:

> The ratio of $AB:AC$ is $1:\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$.

So it was correct, after all. $1:\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ expressed as a fraction is $1/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!